# How to create form with a doctrine entity with a non primary key value in the request?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to create a specific form typy for a doctrine entity that contains other doctrine entities for some of its properties. In the request body, the values that are mapped to the body keys are primary keys of the entity. 
For example:

```
namespace MyProject\MyBundle\Form;

class SomeFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder->add('name');
        // This field in the form **does** use a primary key in the request body.
        $builder->add('thisEntity', 
                      'entity', 
                      [
                          'class' => 'MyProject\MyBundle\Entity\ThisEntity',
                          'property' => 'id'
                      ]
                  );
        // This field in the form **does not** use a primary key in the request body.
        $builder->add('thatEntity',
                      'entity', 
                      [
                          'class' => 'MyProject\MyBundle\Entity\ThatEntity',
                          'property' => 'nonPK'
                      ]
                  );
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver
            ->setDefaults([
                'data_class' => 'Pulse\APIBundle\Entity\Project',
                'csrf_protection'   => false
            ]);
    }

    // ...
}
```

And in my test, I would like the format of my request body to retrieve an entity based on its non primary key value. As shown here:

```
<?php
namespace MyProject\MyBundle\Tests\Controller;

class SomeControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testPostRequest()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $bodyContent = [
            "name" => "HelloWorld",
            "thisEntity" => 1, // primary key (labeled @Id in doctrine annotation mapping)
            "thatEntity" => 1234, // non primary key identifier (not labeled as @Id in doctrine annotation mapping)
        ];
        $jsonContent = json_encode($bodyContent);
        $client->request(
            'POST',
            '/test',
            [],
            [],
            ['CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'],
            $jsonContent
        );

        $response = $client->getResponse();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now, after my request, I am receiving a null value for the 'thatEntity' entity whereas 'thisEntity' will properly map to some fixture I loaded with the ID I passed in the request. So how can I map this value I send in the request to the specific entity I want without the value being a primary key? I am at a loss for how to get this to happen. I have tried using Symfony form event listeners with no luck because the property mapping turns the value to null in between the FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT and FormEvents::SUBMIT events. Additionally, the proper getters and setters are in each entity, so that is not the problem.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: How is your Test controller handling the POST request?  You should be able to receive your POST values and use them to retrieve the correct entities.  If you are passing the POST request through the Symfony handleRequest() method to bind the form data - Symfony is still going to expect the primary keys for "thatEntity" in order to bind them correctly.  Setting "property" to "nonPk" will only change the text that is displayed on the frontend in your dropdown select.  The individual items in the select box on the frontend will still contain the entity primary keys - which get posted back.